# "When" does the compiler implicitly declare a default constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, constructor

I know that compiler will generate a default constructor if we don't declare it.

And "when" is the point I got confused.

A:

```
class Base {};
int main()
{
    return 0;   
}
```

B:

```
class Base {};
int main()
{
    Base b;   // Declare a Base object.
    return 0;
}
```

The A and B difference is only that B declares a real object of Base.
At my point, only when we declare a real object and the compiler finds no constructors does it generate a default constructor.

My question is that:

1. Will code fragment A generate a default constructor of Base?
2. Does any tool help to check the result? I use Visual Studio 2010, and /d1 reportAllClassLayout seems useless.

Comment: Do you mean what the standard says, or what your implementation does? The end result of what the implementation does matches what the standard requires, but the way it achieves that result will likely be subtly different.

Comment: What surprised me is that question is not a duplicate

Comment: @hvd Actually, I want to know what compiler has done with my implementation. Angew gives a very clear explanation, and I still want to know is there any way make us understand what compiler really do?

Comment: @MikeHung What the implementation really does is more complicated. For a simple example, if the constructor is never called (not even from other translation units -- likely because it's not available to other translation units) and the compiler knows this, it doesn't need to define the constructor. (Note: no constructor is called in your code, as your class is a POD type.) It should be clear that not defining a function that is never called will not affect the behaviour of the program, but it may affect the output of any tools that show you whether the constructor has been defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting C++11.

`[class.ctor]§5`:

> A default constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

`[class.ctor]§6`:

> A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is *implicitly defined* when it is odr-used (3.2) to create an object of its class type (1.8) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

This means that it's declared when your class is defined, and defined (as `inline`) when it's first used in the given translation unit.

In your case, this means that code fragment `A` will contain a declaration (but not a definition) of the default constructor, while fragment `B` will contain both.

Comment: @ST3 I can't comment on your answer as it's deleted, but I don't want to leave your question without reply: "Why prefer default-generated copy ctor?" In no particular order: **Maintenance.** The generated default will always handle all data members, even if you add some later. **Moves.** By not providing the copy ctor/assignment op, you let the compiler generate both these and the move ctor/assignment op (if it conforms better than VC does). **Performace.** A class without user-provided copy ctors/assignment ops can be *trivially copyable,* which some algorithms can use for optimisation.

Answer (score 3):

The *declaration* of special member functions (default constructors, copy constructor, etc.) always happens as part of the class definition. So both of your examples are the same with regards to `Base` having a declared default constructor.

A separate question is when a special member function is implicitly *defined*. This is usually deferred until an actual ODR-use of the member function.

Answer (score 0):

Best visualised information what is generated when is in the [presentation](https://accu.org/conf-docs/PDFs_2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf), here is the slide cited from the presentation:
[image]