# Generate the default constructor in Clang

Tags: c++, clang++

I'm trying to extract an AST from Clang using a plugin and I would like to get the "source code" for defaulted constructors.

For example, in my source code I have:

```
class T { public: T() = default; }
```

In the Clang AST the `getBody()` member of the constructor object returns `null`. Is there someway to get the default implementation as a `Stmt`?

In this case it would return `{}` but in the general case it would involve calling parent constructors etc.

A simple example, write the following in a file:

```
class P { }
int main() {
  // P x;
  return 0;
}
```

This file will not generate any constructor code (you can dump the AST with (`clang++ -Xclang -ast-dump  -fsyntax-only test-ctor.cpp`), but if you uncomment the `P x` line, then the same command will generate a default constructor:

```
| CXXConstructorDecl 0x562bdb879eb0 <line:5:5, col:17> col:5 used P 'void () noexcept' default trivial
| `-CompoundStmt 0x562bdb87a570 <col:17>
```

Comment: The AST just represents the source of your cpp file, the constructor code is generated by the subsequent stages of the compiler the source code for generated constructors doesn't exist

Comment: I'm looking at the result of -ast-dump. If I have a simple `class P { };`, then the dump doesn't contain any constructor code, but as soon as I write a simple `int main() { P x; return 0; }` clang generates the AST nodes for the implicit constructors (they even have source location that points to the opening { of the class. The same actually happens for template instantiation. The AST includes the template declaration, as well as all specializations that are mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `Sema` object using functions such as: `DefineImplicitDefaultConstructor`. The `Sema` object is available from a `CompilerInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19347782/5520012) and in C++11,

> A default constructor that is defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is odr-used (3.2) to create an object of its class type (1.8) or when it is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

So there is a CXXConstructorDecl node when `P x` is in the code, namely object `x` is created of its class type `P`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question is more about the clang++ api. Do you know what code in clang actually generates the AST for the constructor?

Comment: @Gregory, I am not aware of any functions in Clang that can generate a constructor. If we are talking about AST, it is just a representation of the source code. It is not "smart" enough to generate an "undefined" constructor. We can only have that node if the constructor is implicitly defined, how that happen ? by having P x in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your point. I understand that the semantics of C++ says that constructors are only generated if they are used. Essentially, what I'm trying to do is ask clang to pretend there is a call to the constructor and generate the code appropriately. Specifically, I want to run a static analysis on a header file that has an implicit constructor. For my static analysis to work, I need to look at the definition an compute a signature for it. But i don't want to re-compute this signature every time the header file is included, only once.